# Lost bitcoin on paper wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, loss

so i got a 0.8 btc on my paper wallet..and usually i checked the balance on daily basis on blockchain.info.

And weird thing happened yesterday,my paper wallet sent my btc with total amount of 0.2btc to unknown address..
And i swear i keep my paper wallet safely and never get exposed..after learning that ,i decide to transfer all remaining btc on my wallet on blockchain apps.

Please anybody can answer here is my paper wallet address.
this.https://blockchain.info/address/14w344ohpe2M35BkScgcFdANuei5MPK49Z

And here the transaction.
https://blockchain.info/tx/8d1d918dcd045732c79541662309b9fe83e7faea99e3e0e757e3620167b2bb7a

Comment: How did you create the paperwallet? On any dubious website maybe?

Comment: From bitaddress.org

Comment: Plus ,i have never import the key.and idk how did the btc was sending over.because the fund inside my paper wallet wasnt totally transfered to that address.it took only 0.2 out of my 0.8 btc.

Comment: Well you must have exposed it somehow when you checked the balance, because look at the timestamps. Happened in the same day as you checked your balance, and just a little over 1 hour apart.

Comment: @Chak but..as its all fund required to be transfered to new address if it was exposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the ones with knowledge of the private key on that paper are able to send money from your address. If it's somebody else who also has your private key, it's weird that he/she didn't sent the entire balance.

Since it's impossible - let me repeat that, impossible - to send the funds without the private key, that leaves yourself as the only likely candidate who sent the 0,2 bitcoin.

Possibly you were performing another action like exchanging bitcoin for an altcoin using Shapeshift and you didn't (yet) correlate that event with the 0,2 transfer.

Comment: Hmmm..i guess.probally someone get access on my private key.since my brother was the only one at home during that event occur..can it be him??but he didnt even know about bitcoin yet..thats what he said..all he knew that im investing on bitcoin and having a paper wallet..can it be him?

Comment: Maybe he let a friend in the house who knew how Bitcoin works.

Answer (score -1):

I think his computer is compromised. I had a guy I know tell me today he had the same happen to him. He created a paper wallet from bitcoinpaperwallet, generated a key in offline mode. He printed out the key and deleted all traces off it. Went back online, sent the money and within 1 minute it was all gone. Someone could easily create malware to monitor for such a key generations and then send it home once the internet is back up.

For me personally, I feel its safer on an exchange because you have 2-factor auth...
Exchanges have gone down in the past, but its rare